# How to identify Weekdays in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, date-formatting

Good Morning,

I am trying to find an alternative to Weekday for Oracle, for some reason our version does not recognize the Weekday function.  It keeps throwing an error,

WeekDay: Invalid Identifier.

I am trying to use it in a Where Statement:

```
Where
Weekday(OR_Log.Surgery_DAte) not in (1,7)
```

To weed out any Saturday or Sunday surgeries.  This is to update code from Teradata to Oracle.

Oracle V. 12C

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004645/how-to-get-the-week-day-name-from-a-date

Comment: It's a good idea to check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/index.html) rather than just being puzzled when something you typed turns out not to be an actual thing.

Answer (score 5):

Your version of Oracle doesn't recognise 'weekday' because that is not an [Oracle function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Functions.html).

You can use [the `to_char()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-datetime.html) to get a day number, but it's dependent on NLS settings, so safer not to reply on it. Day names are also NLS-language-dependent, but that can at least be overridden as part of the function call:

```
where to_char(OR_Log.Surgery_Date, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') not in ('Sat', 'Sun')
```

The `'Dy'` format element [is described in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-49B32A81-0904-433E-B7FE-51606672183A), along with all the others. Note that `'DY'` gives you the day abbreviation in uppercase, and `'Day'` or `'DAY'` give you the full day name in mixed/uppercase; but those are padded with spaces by default (as are abbreviations in other languages...); but you could add a modifier if you want the full day names for readability:

```
where to_char(OR_Log.Surgery_Date, 'FMDay', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') not in ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
```

Comment: How come `WeekDay`  [shows up in the function reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41183_01/DR/WeekDay.html)?

Comment: @citynorman - that documentation is for Oracle DAL (data access layer), not Oracle RDBMS. They have a lot of products, including other DBs like MySQL, all documented on the same site - which can make search results confusing. Particularly when the product name isn't in the URL, or as in this case, anywhere on the page.