# How to return weekday name from date

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to add a column next to my existing date column which gives the corresponding name of the day of the week.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
a.transaction_date,
to_char(date 'a.transaction_date','DAY') as Day
FROM transactions_table a
```

Trying for: Mon, Tue, Wed, etc..  Sadly, the database is returning ORA-01841 error instead. Normally, my date column returns a date like this: dd-mmm-yy

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004645/how-to-get-the-week-day-name-from-a-date

Comment: What data type is `a.transaction_date`? And why have you put that inside single quotes, tryign to make it part of a date *literal* when it is a column?

Comment: Also you've used the DAY format model and referred twice to the day *name*; but then showed the day *abbreviations* (Mon rather than Monday). Which do you actually want? And in all-uppercase or mixed-case?

Comment: Yep, I shouldn't have had single quotes as the field is a DATE field. Full uppercase name is fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `Dy` pattern :

```
select to_char(transaction_date,'Dy') 
  from transactions_table
```

If you need a different language consider a third argument :

```
select to_char(transaction_date,'Dy','nls_date_language=turkish')
  from transactions_table
```

*P.S. I considered English language as default in the first query, if it's not default language for your database, then consider the second query by replacing `turkish` with `english`.*

Comment: you're welcome @Roostir , if you find the answer helpful, please accept it, by this way, the question is considered as being solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try below -

```
SELECT DISTINCT
a.transaction_date,
to_char(date a.transaction_date,'DAY') as Day
FROM transactions_table a
```

Comment: There is a spurious `DATE` keyword inside the `to_char()` function and the `DAY` format model will return the full name of the day rather than the three-letter abbreviated version.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that transaction_date is a date datatype...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
a.transaction_date,
to_char(a.transaction_date,'DAY') as Day
FROM transactions_table a
```

if it is varchar2 then you could just convert it to date first, using your date format

```
SELECT DISTINCT
a.transaction_date,
to_char(to_date(a.transaction_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy'),'DAY') as Day
FROM transactions_table a
```

for instance:

```
select to_char(to_date('08/09/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),'DAY') as Day from dual;
```

Comment: `'a.transaction_date'` is a string literal. Without the single quotes is a table alias and column name. Also, the `DAY` format model will return the full name of the day not the abbreviated version of the name.

Comment: Yep, it's a DATE type. Your first solution works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`date 'a.transaction_date'` is trying to mix a [date literal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1) with a variable column value, but then also putting the column name inside single quotes, You end up essesntially doing:

```
to_date('a.transaction_date', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

which also gets ORA-01841, for perhaps clearer reasons.

If `transaction_date` is already a date then just refer to that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
a.transaction_date,
to_char(a.transaction_date,'DAY') as Day
FROM transactions_table a
```

If it's a string - which it should not be! - then convert that value to a date properly:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
a.transaction_date,
to_char(to_date(a.transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),'DAY') as Day
FROM transactions_table a
```

... or using whatever format mask is appropriate.

Also be aware that `DAY` (and the abbreviated `DY`, or `Dy`, which might be what you actually want) output depends on your NLS date language, but you can override that if you want it to always be in English, for instance:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
a.transaction_date,
to_char(a.transaction_date,'DY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') as Day
FROM transactions_table a
```

Quick demo using a CTE:

```
-- CTE for dummy date
with transactions_table(transaction_date) as (
  select date '2019-01-01' from dual
  union all
  select date '2019-09-01' from dual
)
-- actual query
SELECT DISTINCT
a.transaction_date,
to_char(a.transaction_date,'Dy','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') as Day
FROM transactions_table a
/

TRANSACTIO DAY         
---------- ------------
2019-01-01 Tue         
2019-09-01 Sun
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Format Models](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
a.transaction_date,
to_char(a.transaction_date, 'DY') as Day_Abbr, -- This will print out an abbriviation like "MO" for Monday
to_char(a.transaction_date, 'DAY') as Day, -- This will print out a whole day, like "MONDAY"
substr(to_char(a.transaction_date, 'DAY'),1,3) as Day_My_Abbr -- This will print out your wanted abbriviation, like "MON"
FROM transactions_table a
```

Comment: 'MONTAG' is abbreviated to 'MO'; if the date language is set to English then you get 'MONDAY' and 'MON' - no need to substr. (The OP has shown the English abbreviation, so I'm assuming that's the language they're using by default...)